# Resolving Chrome Extension Communication Issue: Modifying App Variable State from Content-Script to Background.js

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I hope you will be fine,
I am a developing a chrome extension and I am a complete beginner, I am Experiencing a Chrome Extension communication issue between content-script and background.js.
I am successfully sending a message from contentScript to background.js upon API request, but need to modify a variable's counter state in my app OR is there any way to do an updation or a state update in the App. I Want to update a state in the app or set a localstorage item to be accessed in the Extension but not getting it, Any solutions?
I AM USING REACT JS.
Thanks in advance for your help.

content-script.js code:

```
         let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8051/start-counter';
         let secretkey = "someSecretKey"
         let userId = "someUserId"

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                secretkey: secretkey
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ userId }),
        };

 fetch(apiUrl, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('response', data);
                // Send message to background script
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    action: 'taskCompleted',
                    taskName: taskNameValue,
                    selectedProject: selectedProject ? selectedProject.project : null
                });
              

                //Hide the popup after successful request.
                const popup = document.querySelector("#popup");
                if (popup) {
                    popup.style.display = "none";
                }
            })

            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

background.js code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === 'taskCompleted') {
        handleTaskCompleted(request.taskName, request.selectedProject);
        //Want to update a state in the app or set a localstorage item to be accessed in the Extension but not being able to do it
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, { type: 'updateState' });

    }
});
```

I have searched the whole stackoverflow but didn't found a solution and still trying to figure out,

Comment: Show your manifest.json and indicate where your app is loaded. Clarify whether you use chrome.storage.local or localStorage.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the content script? Did you debug your extension? You need to know whether fetch in the content script is failing, communication (between content script, background page, or your application in the tab) does not work, or maybe your tab does not exist while your extension is trying to send a message from the background page. If you spot that place it will be easier for us to help you. Also, are you using MV2 or MV3?

Comment: @wOxxOm! I am using chrome.storage.local to store the variable, but I want to update a state or set a local storage from the background when it received a message from content-script which can be then accessed in the App(I mean the Extension),

Comment: @akaras Thanks for you response.
No I don't see any errors in the content-script. Look All I want is to get notified in My Extension when the API call in the content-script is successful.

My case is that I am starting a timer-counter for a specific task from the content-script using a popup which sends an API request to the counter server(local-server). At that time I want to update a state in My Extension to see that the counter has been started.
I am beginner I don't understand things easily, Thanks for you help again.

Comment: @wOxxOm here is My manifest.json, I haven't studied the Extensions docs fully yet...
I have removed the permissions, name and icons tabs due to the text size of the comment.
`{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://www.google.com/*",
      ],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "css": ["contentScript.css"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type":"module"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}`

Comment: Assuming the "app" is index.html it runs only when shown so you can use chrome.runtime.onMessage in the app during that time. At the start of app's script you'll read chrome.storage.local to get the value you saved previously in your content script or in the background script. See also https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reply, But I have tried that,
But My case is different, I have set items using chrome.storage.local, but when I try to get it in the app that's not available inside My React App(Extension) and When I use the chrome.storage.local.get in one of my React component it gives error that : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local') which cannot be resolved.
Can the set items using chrome.storage.local can be accessed by localStorage.getItem?

Comment: 1) This is why you must clarify where each script is declared and where it runs. Looks like your app is not in the extension but in the web page in the tab? In that case you can use DOM messaging with the content script via `CustomEvent` + `dispatchEvent` or [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) directly. 2) If it's index.html in the popup then you probably open it as a file or from localhost, which is a mistake. Open it by clicking the extension's icon in the toolbar. 3) localStorage if not chrome.storage.local, it's a different thing.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks again for you help!
I am using react to create this Extension, I build it and then upload it as Load Unpacked this is what I watched in a tutorial is this correct or can you provide me with some tips?

Comment: Looks like your app is not in the extension but in the web page in the tab?
Ans: it's not in the webpage it's in the Extension. I can communicate with it as normal Extensions.
3) localStorage if not chrome.storage.local, it's a different thing
Ans: Yes I saw that they are different.
No what about my case? I need to read the docs carefully or can you prefer some other docs or any related links etc. Appreciate your help

Comment: Add "permissions":["storage"] to manifest.json.

Comment: It's already in there:
`"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "bookmarks",
    "cookies",
    "webNavigation",
    "notifications"
  ],`

Comment: @wOxxOm! Can you investigate My issue if you have some time?
I mean can you take a look if I provide the required code?
I am not overwhelmed by any issue, but this issue wasted My so much time

Comment: You need to make the question understandable as I suggested above. Describe where and how exactly each file is loaded. Where the app is, how it is opened or injected or executed. Edit the question, don't do it in the comments.